# most efficient way to set an image

Tags: java, image, performance, processing-efficiency, memory-efficient

There must be some more efficient way to set an image isn't there? Or is this as good as it gets?

```
     public Image setImage(String img){
        ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(setURL("Images/" + img));
        Image image;
          image = imageIcon.getImage();
          //imgWidthTemp = image.getWidth(null);
          //imgHeightTemp = image.getHeight(null);
          return image; 
     }

    public URL setURL(String url){
       String Url = url;
       try{
        URL imgURL = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(url);
        if(imgURL != null){
           return imgURL;
        }
       }catch(NullPointerException e){}
         return null;
     }
```

I really don't need the `setURL()` method, it just made things cleaner and easier to handle. I just want to know if there is a more efficient way of setting a custom image if at all. It is still a lot of code to write even without those two methods. Does it get any simpler? I mean why can't we just make a new image instead of first making an `ImageIcon` and then saying `Image myImage = ImageIcon.getImage()`. Not complaining, but that would be alot of code without a method or two if you have 2000+ images to set(take minecraft for example huh? that's quite a few images if I says so myself). And videogames mostly just have tons of images rather than the code being only like 30% of the code sometimes.

Comment: Have you benchmarked? Do you know that this code is a bottleneck in your application?

Comment: Your question doesn't make a lot of sense.  The code you present is not "setting an image".  It is *loading* an image.  And the handling of null in the (misnamed!) `setUrl` method is just bizarre.

Comment: say what now? I don't get what you mean by benchmarked or a "bottleneck in my application". please clarify.

Comment: Read this:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benchmarking.  And this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_%28computer_programming%29.  The point is that until you have measured your code's actual performance, it is a bad idea to look for ways to make it go faster.

Comment: @StephenC i know it isn't setting an Image and that it is just loading an image, so let me reword: Is there a more efficient way to load an image and then set it? and it actually doubles as the loader and setter for the purpose that i made it to be used like so: `Image Head = setImage("Head_model_01.png");`

Comment: *"I know it isn't setting an Image and that it is just loading an image"*  - So why did you say that it was?  Are you *deliberately* trying to mislead people???  Update the Question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear what you are really trying to do here, but the Java Tutorial has a section on working with images that includes material on [loading images](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html).  Read it for code that shows the recommended way to do it.

I'm not an expert on this, but I would expect that the direct way recommended by the tutorial will be faster than the indirect approach of using `ImageIcon`.  (But I haven't benchmarked it!!)

---

There are other things wrong with your code.  In particular, the `setUrl` method is just bizarre.

- The name `setUrl` is a misnomer.  The method is not "setting" anything.  Rather, it is attempting to map a pathname to a resource URL.
- The try-catch is unnecessary.  Nothing in that code *should* be throwing an NPE.
- If you remove the unnecessary try-catch, then the logic boils down to this:

  ```
      URL imgURL = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(url);
      if (imgURL != null) {
         return imgURL;
      } else {
         return null;
      }
  ```

  That's crazy / silly stuff!  Just do this:

  ```
      return getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(url);
  ```

---

Finally, there is an important point that you need to understand about practical optimization.

It is a well known fact that people's intuition on whether a program will be fast or slow, and what makes it fast or slow ... is poor.  Rather than relying on your intuition (i.e. guessing what the problems are, or are going to be), it is better to do the following:

1. Get your program working.
2. Measure how fast it is doing a real task.  This is called *benchmarking*.
3. Ask yourself if it is already fast enough.  If it is, then don't waste your time optimizing.
4. Use a *profiler* to find out where the *performance hotspots* or *bottlenecks* in the code are.
5. Optimize the sections of code that have been identified as bottlenecks.  Don't spend time optimizing code that isn't a bottleneck, because that effort will be wasted.

Comment: So I'm guessing that's code efficient for getting the image's URL ?

Comment: 1) I don't understand what "that" is.  2)  Don't guess.  Profile.  See my completed answer.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe it was that simple. But hey, ya can't be too hard on the noob can ya? (me) after all my mentor directed me to this:http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/ : yet another insignificant programming notes